# angularJS validation method with custom input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So i have these new custom inputs which can be found here.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3

Now the only issue is that the validation i had on this is no longer working.

Ideally i want the line to turn red when theres a validation issue with the text undernetih
Heres the code for one of the input boxes

```
    <input type="text" required placeholder="&#xf040; Event Title" class="validate" ng-model="data.title">
    <span class="fa fa-asterisk req"></span>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <!-- <label>Event Title</label> -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="speech help-block has-error" ng-messages="details.title.$error" ng-if="details.title.$dirty || detailsSubmitted" role="alert">
  <div ng-message="required" class="errormsg">Please enter a Title.</div>
  <div ng-message="custom" class="errormsg">{{errorMessages.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this example is working

```
 <form action="" method="get" name="details" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="text" name="title" required placeholder="Event Title" class="validate" ng-model="data.title">

        <span class="fa fa-asterisk req"></span>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <div class="speech help-block has-error" ng-messages="details.title.$error" ng-if="details.title.$dirty || detailsSubmitted" role="alert">
            <div ng-message="required" class="errormsg">Please enter a Title.</div>
            <div ng-message="custom" class="errormsg">{{errorMessages.title}}</div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: you removed the input field which its against?

Comment: was mistake :) sorry